# In MS SQL how do I find out what tables have not been queried or updated in a long time?

Tags: maintenance, sql-server

I'm maintaining a database that is being shared by a few systems. Over the years a few of those systems have been deprecated and lots of the tables are actually orphaned. Is there a query I can run to find out which tables have not been used since a certain date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sys.objects table keeps track of the last time a table's structure was modified but the closest you are going to get for finding out the last time a table's data was updated or used is by querying sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.  This keeps track of index updates (including heap's, or tables without an index).  **The catch is, it only keeps track of this data since the last time you're server was restarted.**

```
select db_name(database_id) dbname,
object_name(object_id,database_id) oname,
MAX(CASE WHEN last_user_update < last_system_update THEN last_system_update ELSE last_user_update END) as LastUpdated 
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
group by database_id,object_id
order by db_name(database_id),object_name(object_id,database_id)
```

This sample query was borrowed from the following link:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic852747-146-1.aspx#bm852757